# Rust: conditional trait inheritance

Tags: rust, traits

For example, I want to write the trait for containers in Rust:

```rust
trait Container: Default {
    type ValueType;
}
```

But also I want that all `Container`s also can be `Clone`d only when `Container::ValueType` can be `Clone`d:

```rust
// not Rust code
trait Container: Default + Clone if Self::ValueType: Clone {
    type ValueType;
}
```

Of course, I could conditionally implement `Clone` trait for the concrete container itself:

```rust
struct MyVec<T> {}

impl<T: Clone> Clone for MyVec<T> {/**/}
```

or use `derive(Clone)`, but I want to express my intention for `Container` trait, not for implementing types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This similar syntax exists:

```
trait Container: Default + Clone where Self::ValueType: Clone {
                              // ^^^^^
    type ValueType;
}
```

But it isn't conditional, `Container` can only be implemented for types that statisfy *all* constraints: `Default`, `Clone`, and `Self::ValueType` is `Clone`.

---

I'm not sure this would be useful. Rust trait constraints are explicit, meaning you can't use something unless the constraint is there. So you'd have to include them in the constraints anyway.

```
fn use_container<C: Container>(c: C)
where
    C: Clone,
    C::ValueType: Clone
{
  let _ = c.clone();
  let _ = c.get_element().clone();
}
```

And you have to implement `Clone` on the concrete types regardless.

If your goal is just to indicate that *"for implementations of `Container` if the elements are `Clone` then the container should be clone"*, the prevailing pattern in idiomatic Rust is to only constrain what you need when you need it. (i.e. if a function needs to clone the container, constrain on `C: Clone`; if a function only needs to clone an element, constrain on `C::ValueType: Clone`).

Comment: I've never seen the `where Self::ValueType: Clone` syntax before. Is the meaning the same as when specifying the constraint on the `ValueType` itself using `type ValueType: Clone`?

Comment: @user4815162342 In this instance they'd be the same and I'd prefer the latter. The `where` syntax is available since it can apply to more things. For example: `trait Container: Iterator where Self::Item: Clone`.

Comment: Oh, right, that makes sense and I've  seen it in that variant. In more complex traits it's often disambiguated as `where <Self as Iterator>::Item: Clone`.